# A variable with value of one entry in typescript enum

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have TS enum:

```
enum A {
   Foo = 'foo',
   Bar = 'bar',
}

const fn = (a: A) => {};
```

I want to make sure that argument `a` equals to one of the properties from enum `A`. How to type it correctly, so argument `a` has value `foo` or `bar`?

P.S. I dont want to use hardcoded `a: 'foo' | 'bar'`

Answer (score 2):

You already did it.

```js
enum A {
   Foo = 'foo',
   Bar = 'bar',
}

const fn = (a: A) => {};
```

If U are using enums, you can't call `fn` function with `foo` argument, instead U should use `A.Foo`.